# Trying to connect odata Source to tableau - trying to trouble shoot error

Tags: url, odata, tableau-api

I am hoping someone might be able to help me with this,

I unable to connect https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

however, it comes to using our endpoint, which is $metadata

I get an error message 'Bad Odata format make sure you are using a URL that points to a valid OData  source

Also, I can open this URL in my web browser

I can't seem to troubleshoot, this can anyone suggest anything I can try?

I have also tried changing the IP to a name, but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your OData server returns XML data instead of JSON.
Change your configuration in JSON format it will work.